# <sj:autocompleter> on text change

Tags: jquery-ui, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using jQuery autocompleter populated by an AJAX action returning an JSON object.

The problem is that when I enter text, I see the whole list, even if i set "autocomplete" to "true".

How to display only Strings corresponding to what I enter?

This my jQuery autocompleter :

```
<s:url id="paysList" action="paysList" namespace="/ajax">
    <s:param name="nameRegion">EUROPE</s:param>
</s:url>

<label for="nomPays_0">
    <s:text name="label.nameCountry" />
</label>

<br>

<sj:autocompleter name="nomPays[0]" 
                  id="nomPays_0"
                  forceValidOption="true" 
                  key="label.nameCountry" 
                  href="%{paysList}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the `<sj:head/>` tag in your `<head>` section ?

```
<head>
    <sj:head jqueryui="true"/>
</head>
```

as described in the [Official Documentation ?](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag)

Otherwise, try by using the `onChangeTopics` as described in the [Official Showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action);

Click on <kbd>Widgets</kbd> -> <kbd>Autocompleter</kbd> -> <kbd>Autocompleter JSON</kbd>, then take a look at JSP and JavaScript code